# How to display warning message inside manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, string-manipulation, physics, fluid-dynamics

Using the code shown, Reynolds number is calculated for given parameters. Is it possible to display a warning message to the user if a parameter is outside applicable range? e.g., if the fluid velocity is more than 5 m/s.

```
Manipulate["Reynolds number: " <> ToString@Style[Rey[v], 14],Text[Style["Reynolds number calculator", 16]], Delimiter, {{v, 1.5,"Velocity of Fluid(m/s): "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 7}, {{roh, 1, "Fluid Density (Kg/m^3): "},ControlType -> InputField,FieldSize -> 7},{{dia, 0.01, "Hydraulic Diameter (m) "},ControlType -> InputField,FieldSize -> 7}, {{muh, 0.00089, "Dynamic Viscosity (Kg/ms): "},ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 7}, Delimiter,Item[Button["Calculate", Nothing, BaseStyle -> {15}]],LabelStyle -> {14}, ContentSize -> 310,Initialization :> {Rey[v_] := (roh*v*dia)/muh}, TrackedSymbols :> All]
```

Now if the user puts a velocity value of more than 5 m/s, a warning message should appear: "Velocity should be less than 5 m/s".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a quick way to do it. Just add another small window that shows the `status`. In there you can add messages.

[image]

```
Manipulate[

 Grid[{{Row[{"Reynolds number: ", ToString@Style[Rey[v], 14]}]},
   {Row[{"Status: ", Text[If[v <= 5, Style["Ok", Blue], 
        Style["Warning, v too large!!", Red]]]}]}
   }, Frame -> True, Alignment -> Left],

 Text[Style["Reynolds number calculator", 16]],
 Delimiter,
 {{v, 1.5, "Velocity of Fluid(m/s): "}, ControlType ->InputField, FieldSize -> 7},
 {{roh, 1, "Fluid Density (Kg/m^3): "}, ControlType ->InputField, FieldSize -> 7},
 {{dia, 0.01, "Hydraulic Diameter (m) "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 7},
 {{muh, 0.00089, "Dynamic Viscosity (Kg/ms): "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 7},
 Delimiter,
 Item[Button["Calculate", Nothing, BaseStyle -> {15}]], 
 LabelStyle -> {14}, ContentSize -> 310,
 Initialization :> {Rey[v_] := (roh*v*dia)/muh},
 TrackedSymbols :> All
 ]
```

Feel free to improve the layout.

**Update**

> Yes, I want to display a message inside manipulate... but only when
> the condition goes wrong.

In this case, how about

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 If[v <= 5,
  Row[{"Reynolds number: ", ToString@Style[Rey[v], 14]}]
  ,
  Row[{Text[Style["Warning, v too large!!", Red]]}]
  ],
 Text[Style["Reynolds number calculator", 16]], Delimiter, {{v, 1.5, 
   "Velocity of Fluid(m/s): "}, ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 7}, {{roh, 1, "Fluid Density (Kg/m^3): "}, 
  ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 7}, {{dia, 0.01, "Hydraulic Diameter (m) "}, 
  ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 7}, {{muh, 0.00089, "Dynamic Viscosity (Kg/ms): "}, 
  ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 7}, Delimiter, 
 Item[Button["Calculate", Nothing, BaseStyle -> {15}]], 
 LabelStyle -> {14}, ContentSize -> 310, 
 Initialization :> {Rey[v_] := (roh*v*dia)/muh}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> All]
```

Comment: Can it only display warning msg when v is more than 5 m/s? I don't want to put a status window for this.

Comment: @ASHISHSHUKLA, the title of your post suggest that you want a message inside manipulate?

Comment: Yes, I want to display a message inside manipulate... but only when the condition goes wrong.

Comment: @ASHISHSHUKLA updated.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you so much for your time and efforts... This is what I was looking through...